# Does this statement hit the database?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a .NET application which executes a statement like this:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromKML('
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>-71.1663,42.2614 
                -71.1667,42.2616</coordinates>
        </LineString>');
```

There is no need for tables or where clause, I'm basically using it as a converter.

So my question is does my application hit the database when i issue this command or does the local postgress dll take care of it in memory?

Comment: Why not shutdown the database and try? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will hit the database, which basically means that it will be much slower than it needs to be.

You should try to write a method thaat performs the conversion without using the database, and call that method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I will hit the database, however the overhead is not so huge, usually you won't notice that.